# Cannot update the order status in history tap with Opencart 2.0.2.0

Tags: opencart2.x

I got the problem with my Opencart (Ver2.0.2.0). I am not able to update the Order Status under the History tap in admin panel. When I click the button "Add History" and it comes out with a message:

> "Warning: Order could not be found!"

Please kindly find my screen shot for your reference and appreicate someone can tell me how to fix it?

[Please see my screenshot here - Update Order staus not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY0Ye.gif)

Many Thanks

Achilles.c

Answer (score 0):

I checked and Opencart only shows this if order is not in database or Opencart status update function is not getting correct order-id.

Did you try this with other orders too ?

[image: Can check this in ur console]